# Playback on AKPlayer.buffer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

Hello I am recording sound using Audiokit AKNodeRecorder, I then transfer this data to a player, do some processing on it and am now trying to play it again. However I cannot get it to work.

I've tried playing the buffer via the AKPlayer, or creating a new AKAudioFile no dice.

Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
tape = recorder.audioFile!
player.load(audioFile: tape)
player.buffering = .always
recorder.stop()
var globalAudioFile: AKAudioFile?

if let avAudioPCMBuffer = player.buffer {

    //do processing on avAudioPCMBuffer here

    do {
        globalAudioFile = try AKAudioFile()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Recorder Error: Unable to open AudioFile: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    do {
        globalAudioFile = try AKAudioFile(forWriting: (globalAudioFile?.url)!,
                                          settings: (globalAudioFile?.processingFormat.settings)!)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Recorder Error: cannot write to \(globalAudioFile?.fileNamePlusExtension)")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    do {
        try globalAudioFile?.write(from: avAudioPCMBuffer)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Recoder Error: Unable to write buffer to AudioFile: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    if let audioFile = globalAudioFile {
        let bufferedPlayer = audioFile.player
        bufferedPlayer.play()
    }
}

//later when I wish to play:

if let audioFile = globalAudioFile {
    let bufferedPlayer = audioFile.player
    bufferedPlayer.play()
}
```

When I try to play I get an exception.

I created an example project here if anyone would like to test drive it: https://gitlab.com/Donwangugi/AVAudioPCMBufferExample

I appreciate the help :)

Comment: what is the processing you want to do?

Comment: I wanted to see if I can do some noise suppression, I was going to try to use something like this: https://people.xiph.org/~jm/demo/rnnoise/

Comment: currently AKPlayer pulls its buffer from the associated file and will overwrite the buffer often - what would be best for you is to allow it to play custom buffers or to just write a buffer based player yourself.

Comment: @RyanFrancesconi by playing custom buffers do you mean modifying AKPlayer or subclass AKPlayer to do so?

Comment: i wrote AKPlayer - so it would be something I can add for you - just a little short on time at the moment.

Comment: alternatively, you could write your own buffer based player.